# Normalizing/Plotting textual data, and testing for validity on a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

This is from [GHTorrent](https://ghtorrent.org/) after being run through [supervised fastText](https://fasttext.cc/). I wouldn't put a lot of faith into my model, but if anyone wants it, I'm happy to provide it, as well as the raw data. It's currently in BigQuery, but I can export it and put it somewhere for you. I have 6 days of data, one from each month, of the first half of 2019 - about 164MM rows total. I intend to put it on Kaggle later either way.

```
   | actor_gender | sentiment          | author_gender
---|--------------|--------------------|--------------|---
0  | Male         |   __label__terse   |    Male      |
1  | Female       |   __label_positive |    Male      |
2  | Male         |   __label_negative |    Male      |
```

I used `groupby()` (on only **author_gender** - cross-sentiment would be a terrific bonus) to generate this:

```
author_gender  sentiment
   
Female     __label__helpful      351809
           __label__negative     500718
           __label__neutral      508554
           __label__positive     513237
           __label__terse        478805
Male       __label__helpful     3121180
           __label__negative    4549122
           __label__neutral     4631527
           __label__positive    4679315
           __label__terse       4328896
```

I then normalized it with sklearn:

```
array([[0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.9224484 , 0.91644306],
       [0.97099016, 0.96933   ],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.78670367, 0.77510357]])
```

EDIT: This was MinMax, which in retrospect was not correct as was done - I think I need to apply it over the entire dataframe, not the groupby.

What I would like to do is plot it in a way that accurately represents the data - I was thinking maybe a categorical plot, with the axes as (**sentiment**, **count**) and the gender as the hue, but if there's a better way, I'm all ears. I can't figure out how I need to transform the data into something that Seaborn will work with.

Finally, I need to test the data against the null hypothesis that author_gender (and again, perhaps actor as well) has no impact on the distribution of sentiments. I've read about T-Test, Z-Test, and Chi-Squares, and honestly am lost as to which one is appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess with normalize you mean percentages, maybe something like a stacked barplot, so we can generate a table first to allow also subsequent testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lab = ["__label__helpful","__label__negative","__label__neutral",
       "__label__positive","__label__terse"]

df = pd.DataFrame({'author_gender':np.random.choice(["Female","Male"],1000),
                'sentiment':np.random.choice(lab,1000)})

tab = pd.crosstab(df['sentiment'],df['author_gender'],normalize='index')
```

This is how the table looks like:

```
author_gender   Female  Male
sentiment       
__label__helpful    0.510753    0.489247
__label__negative   0.487685    0.512315
__label__neutral    0.568807    0.431193
__label__positive   0.525773    0.474227
__label__terse  0.542714    0.457286
```

Plot:

```
plot.barh(stacked="True")
```

[image]

For the test, you use a chi-square, in this case, because the data is simulated, you get a p-value close to 1

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency(tab, correction=False)
p
0.9999710076066467
```

Comment: By normalize I meant scale the data, since the actual distribution is heavily skewed. I can figure that part out, though.

Thank you for the crosstab explanation, that's new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I created [LensPy](https://github.com/serant/lenspy) which is designed to automatically aggregate plots based on your viewport so that it’s still fast and interactive. You can [define custom aggregators](https://lenspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#custom-aggregators) which are methods that will take in a slice of your data and aggregate it based on what you deem fit.

Basically this lets you use aggregators that will still yield a large amount of the data (10s of millions) so it should still be fairly accurate when visualizing it.